# Is it possible to find an upper bound and a lower bound for $(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi}))^T(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}(\bar{\xi}))(\xi-\tilde{\xi})$?

Tags: inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, stability, mean-value-theorem

For a system engineering problem I have to solve the problem below, but since I am not a mathematician, I am not sure if I have enough knowledge to solve it.

**Problem definition:** Let $f(\xi) \in \mathcal{C}^1$ be a smooth function with mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ with $p\le n$. With this information, we have the term:
\begin{equation}
\left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right)^\top\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\left(\bar{\xi}\right)\right)\left(\xi-\tilde{\xi}\right) \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where $\xi, \bar{\xi}, \tilde{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and are varying over time. Using the mean-value-theorem, we can prove that
$$\left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right)^\top\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\left(\bar{\xi}\right)\right)\left(\xi-\tilde{\xi}\right)\le \left(\xi-\tilde{\xi}\right)^\top \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\left(\bar{\xi}\right)\right)^\top\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\left(\bar{\xi}\right)\right) \left(\xi-\tilde{\xi}\right)$$
Thus, for \eqref{1} we know that we can find an upperbound for all $\xi, \bar{\xi}, \tilde{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, for the problem, we require a lower bound for all $\xi, \bar{\xi}, \tilde{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ or show that the $\le$ sign can be changed to an equality sign for all $\xi, \bar{\xi}, \tilde{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, I do not know how to show it.

Could one of you help me out?

Comment: The inequality is certainly false in general. Something alike must be true, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

The same reasoning for the upper bound can be applied for the lower bound. Which was:

\begin{equation}
\left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right)^{\top} \leq (\xi - \tilde{\xi})^{\top} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} (\bar{\xi})\right)^{\top}
\end{equation}

Such that taking the transpose of this inequality gives:

\begin{equation}
\left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right) \leq \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} (\bar{\xi})\right) (\xi - \tilde{\xi})
\end{equation}

Filling this into the left hand side of the original inequality gives:

\begin{equation}
0 \leq \left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right)^{\top} \left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right) \leq \left(f(\xi)-f(\tilde{\xi})\right)^{\top} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} (\bar{\xi})\right) (\xi - \tilde{\xi})
\end{equation}

Now the left hand side has a lower bound of 0. Because $x^{\top}x \geq 0$.

Comment: Since the mapping $f$ is multi dimensional, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ the first statement cannot hold, since there is no ordening in vectors. 0 is obviously a trivial lowerbound. Thank you for the answer contribution!